# rournd corner context menu

Tags: android, xml, contextmenu, android-xml

I want to have round corner context menu in android.this code is works fine but the corners dose not have any radius.how to do it?
this is my layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Delet Post"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSharePhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Edit Post"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:background="@color/white"/>


</merge>
```

and my FeedContextMenu for inflating:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_context_menu, this, true);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_container_shadow);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(CONTEXT_MENU_WIDTH, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drawable folder make background.xml and use in 
as

```
 android:background="@drawable/background"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@color/yellowish"
    android:startColor="@color/yellowish" />
   <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp"/>
```